# Why does ajax post encoded data instead of JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, aws-lambda

I have an ajax POST that is encoding the data instead of sending it in JSON format.  I have to be missing something but I have not be able to narrow it down.  The API works in Insomnia but not from code.

I have the content-Type set to application/json and I've tried setting contentType to false and specifying the header explicitly.  The host is receiving the application/json either way.  I've tried sending as a string, as an object and resolving as a function.

```js
data: jsonPacket,
```

```js
data: JSON.stringify(jsonPacket),
```

```js
data:function () {
   return "foo bar";
}
```

All attempts result in encoded text.

**Build the json object**

```
          JSONpacket = {
            "Destination": {
              "ToAddresses": [
                $('email').val()
              ],
                "BccAddresses": [
                  "sombody@somewhere.com"
                ]
            },
            "Message": {
              "Body": {
                "Text": {
                  "Data" : "Test email",
                }
              },
              "Subject": {
                "Data": "Message received from Website"
              }
            },
            "Source": "nobody@nowhere.com"
          };
```

**Make the call**

```
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://x9beos0tm4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage/<sanitized>",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            headers: {
              "x-Api-Key": '**************************'
            },
            data: JSONstringify(JSONpacket),
            success: function (data, status) {
              $('#email_response').html(data);
              $('#email_response').addClass('alert alert-success');
              $('#email_response').slideDown();
              setTimeout(function (e) {
                $('#email_response').slideUp();
                $('#email_response').val('');
                $('#email_response').removeClass('alert alert-success');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#phone').val('');
                $('#message').text('');
              }, 15000);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errMessage) {
              if (errMessage == "")
                errMessage = xhr.statusText + " : " + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.responseJSON.message;
              $('#email_response').addClass('alert alert-danger');
              $('#email_response').html(errMessage);
              $('#email_response').slideDown();
              setTimeout(function (e) {
                $('#email_response').slideUp();
                $('#email_response').html('');
                $('#email_response').removeClass('alert alert-danger');
              }, 15000);
            }
          });
```

**Data received when called from ajax**

```
"Destination%5BToAddresses%5D%5B%5D=sombodey%40somewhere.com&Destination%5BBccAddresses%5D%5B%5D=someonelse%40somewhere.com&Destination%5BBccAddresses%5D%5B%5D=nobody%40nowhere.com&Message%5BBody%5D%5BText%5D%5BData%5D=****+****+contact+Email%0D%0ASent+on+Saturday+August8+17th+2019+%40+10%3A04+am%0D%0A%0D%0AName%3A+******+*********%0D%0AEmail%3A+sombody%40somewhere.com%0D%0APhome%3A+9999999999%0D%0AMessage%3A%0D%0Asdffg%0D%0A&Message%5BSubject%5D%5BData%5D=Message+received+from+Website&Source=nobody%40nowhere.com
```

**Data received when called from Insomnia (like postman)**

```
"body": "{\n  \"Destination\": {\n    \"ToAddresses\": [\n      \"somebody@somewhere.com\",\n        \"somebodyelse@somewhere.com\"    ]\n  },\n  \"Message\": {\n    \"Body\": {\n      \"Text\": {\n        \"Data\": \"Test email body from API\"\n      }\n    },\n    \"Subject\": {\n      \"Data\": \"Different Test Email Subject FROM API\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"Source\": \"webadmin@nowhere.com\"\n}"
```

Comment: What does your `JSONstringify()` function do?

Comment: **Note**: *$('email').val()* , `email` is not an HTML tag.

Comment: Typo posting here - s/b #email

Answer (score 1):

## Fixed it

**Stupid human trick**

Two problems:

```
1.) its JSON.stringify() not JSONstringify()
2.) malformed json:  [$('email').val()] should be $('email').val()
```

Comment: **Note**: *$('email').val()* , `email` is not an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

The \n chars are the linebreaks after they are converted in the JSON.stringify.   If you do a JSON.parse on it you'll get the raw object without those \n characters.